# sql select half distinct half not distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using Microsoft SQL server management studio.

I have a table with some duplication(except the primary key, everything else are the same).

For example: table_now

- MeetingID(Primanry Key)    - CompanyName - MeetingContent
- 1                          - A_Company   - hello
- 2                          - A_Company   - hello
- 3                          - B_company   - apple
- 4                          - B_company   - banana

What I want to do is get a new table with none duplication

table_excepted

- MeetingID(Primanry Key)    - CompanyName - MeetingContent
- 1                          - A_Company   - hello
- 3                          - B_company   - apple
- 4                          - B_company   - banana

I need to get all three column, but when I use

```
SELECT DISTINCT MeetingID, CompanyName, MeetingContent.....
```

it will get the same table since the meetingID is always distinct.
I want to get a thing like

```
SELECT MeetingID, DISTINCT CompanyName, MeetingContent
```

but I don't know how to do it

Thanks.

Comment: `Select min(meetingID), companyName, MeetingContent... From table Group by companyName, MeetingContent ...`

Comment: https://www.w3resource.com/sql/select-statement/queries-with-distinct-multiple-columns.php    try this link it is showing same thing what you want with example.

Comment: I want to create the table_expected with the MeetingID as the primary key, I used " SELECT MIN(MeetingID) as MeetingID, CompanyName, MeetingContent FROM table_now GROUP BY CompanyName, MeetingContent" and i try to set meetingID as primary key, but it does't work. how can i set the primary key at the same time I put these data into the table? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Based on your sample data, you want the `MIN(MeetingID)` in the case of a duplicate entry:

```
SELECT MIN(MeetingID), CompanyName, MeetingContent
FROM table_now
GROUP BY CompanyName, MeetingContent
```

That said, you're likely better off creating the new table, setting `MeetingID` as an identity column, then inserting only the other two distinct column values.

```
CREATE TABLE table_expected
(
 MeetingID int identity (1,1),
 CompanyName varchar(50),
 MeetingContent varchar(50),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_table_expected] PRIMARY KEY (MeetingID ASC)
)

INSERT INTO table_expected (CompanyName, MeetingContent) 
SELECT DISTINCT CompanyName, MeetingContent
FROM table_now
```

Comment: I want to create the table_expected with the MeetingID as the primary key, I used       " SELECT MIN(MeetingID) as MeetingID, CompanyName, MeetingContent
FROM table_now
GROUP BY CompanyName, MeetingContent"         and  i try to set meetingID as primary key, but it does't work.  how can i set the primary key at the same time I put these data into the table? Thanks

Comment: @travis I added the create table script to my answer.  Create the table first, then insert into it.  You will use the bottom query, which by leaving out `MeetingID` from the insert/select, will auto-increment the identity column for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT   MIN(MeetingID),CompanyName,MeetingContent
FROM     [Table_now]
GROUP BY CompanyName,MeetingContent
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use row_number as below:

```
Select * from (
    Select *, RowN = Row_Number() over (partition by CompanyName, MeetingContent order by MeetingId) from yourtable ) a
    Where a.RowN = 1
```

Or you can use top 1 with ties as below:

```
Select top 1 with ties * from yourtable
    order by Row_Number() over (partition by CompanyName, MeetingContent order by MeetingId)
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: use aggregration and min

```
SELECT min(meetingID) as MeetingID, companyName, MeetingContent... 
FROM table 
GROUP BY companyName, MeetingContent...
```

Comment: I use            'SELECT min(meetingID) as MeetingID, companyName, MeetingContent... 
FROM table 
GROUP BY companyName, MeetingContent'       but I can't change MeetingID into primary key, what can i do ?   thanks